# AJAX API currency

Tags: javascript, ajax, api

````
```https://codepen.io/aparandeh/pen/yQjZma?editors=1010```
````

but when I add this
`<h1>Bitcoin Current Price is: <span id="price"></span></h1>`

[image]

it just appear the money in the first line, but the second one is nothing (using same id)

can anyone help me?

Comment: `id` must be unique in the HTML document.

Comment: "but the second one is nothing" - what's your query here?

Comment: @ArunKumarMohan: but when I use class, it's still happen like that

Comment: @user14000833 How're you querying the elements and how're you updating their `innerHTML`?

Comment: @RifatBinReza: I want second line look like this: Bitcoin Current Price is: 59,579.0069 USD (like the first line), sorry for my bad english

Comment: You are using querySelector for getting one element, if you want to get multiple elements for the same id or class, then you'll have to using `querySelectorAll` and then go through and set innerHTML of each one. Or set a different id and store in a separate variable and set the price for that one separately

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works for me:

```js
var btn = document.querySelector("button");

// AJAX Request
var XHR = new XMLHttpRequest();

// On page load, load the price using the default currency selected (USD)
window.addEventListener("load", function(){
    refresh();
});

// On press of the referesh button load the price
btn.addEventListener("click", function()
{
    refresh();
});

// Resend API request when referesh() is invoked.
function refresh()
{
    // Grab the radio buttons, then loop over them and if one is checked, grab its value and send API request using the currency selected
    document.getElementsByName("currency").forEach(function(data)
    {
        // Only run the code block if data.checked === true.
        if(data.checked)
        {
            XHR.onreadystatechange = function()
            {
                if(XHR.readyState === 4 && XHR.status === 200)
                {
                    var price = document.getElementsByClassName("price");
                    for (var i = 0; i < price.length; i++) {
                        price[i].innerHTML = JSON.parse(XHR.responseText).bpi[data.value].rate + " " + data.value; 
                    }
                }
            }
            
            XHR.open("GET", "https://api.coindesk.com/v1/bpi/currentprice.json");
            XHR.send();
        }
    });
}
```

```html
<h1>Bitcoin Current Price is: <span class="price"></span></h1>
<h1>Bitcoin Current Price is: <span class="price"></span></h1>

<form action="">
  <input type="radio" name="currency" value="USD" checked> USD<br>
  <input type="radio" name="currency" value="GBP"> GBP<br>
  <input type="radio" name="currency" value="EUR"> EUR
</form>
<br>
<button>Referesh Data</button>
```

You must write `class=price` instead of `id=price`. Then you can select all elements with class *price* and then with `for` loop you can perform code for every of that.

Also sorry for my bad english :)